# Can anyone help to identify and date this uniform or the medals?

Tags: military, united-kingdom, identification, uniform

Found in my late Aunt's possessions. Photograph of unidentified uniform:

[image]

Comment: I believe the UK

Comment: Are there any stamps or other identifying marks on the back of the photograph that might help us estimate a date?

Answer (score 11):

It looks, with the tapering [*frogging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frog_(fastening)#Military_uniforms) connecting at the single, center row of buttons, you may have a [Royal Horse Artillery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Horse_Artillery) uniform. Some better images can be seem on a forum [here](http://www.victorianwars.com/viewtopic.php?t=2316). Another [forum](https://www.greatwarforum.org/topic/190592-royal-horse-artillery/) has this image. (note similar positioning of the [*aiguillette*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aiguillette#United_Kingdom)).[image]
(Note the feature I identified as an aiguillette may also be described in this case as a busby line, cap line or body line. See (commercial site) [here](https://www.wyedeanstores.com/royal-horse-artillery-officers-gold-long-british-army-body-line).

Another more detailed image of a similar uniform jacket can be found at [Museums Victoria Collections](https://collections.museumvictoria.com.au/items/383880) labeled as 'Jacket - Victorian Horse Artillery, Full Dress, circa 1890' :

[image]

Concerning the medals, they would appear to be [Campaign Medals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_campaign_medals). However without color or a more precise time frame they are difficult to match.

Comment: Thank you .. this is useful information .. Phil

Answer (score -1):

He is indeed Royal Horse Artillery as has been suggested.  The medal ribbons appear to be those of the Queen’s and King’s South Africa medals (of Victoria and Edward VII respectively), that were awarded for the 2nd Anglo/Boer War 1899-1902.  They date the photo to before WW1.[image]

Comment: Hi Frogsmile and welcome to History SE. If you could provide sources or a link or two to backup your answer, that would be great :)

Comment: This seems very unlikely. Both medals listed ([Queen's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen%27s_South_Africa_Medal) and [King's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_South_Africa_Medal)) have a lighter centre stripe, darker side stripes, which is the opposite of what we see in the photograph.

Comment: The type of film used known as Orthochromatic did not show true colours and in some cases distorted light to be dark and dark to be light.  I enclose the ribbons as they are seen side by side in the same way as on the gunner concerned.